# connecting a jquery-ui callback to its handler class

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, coffeescript, jquery

funny JavaScript!  I'm learning it through CoffeeScript, it is fun, but it's also sometimes surprising.

I have a jquery-ui slider and an own class Slider, I create the jquery-ui slider inside of the Slider constructor and register the `Slider.onChange` method as callback for the slide-ui slider `slide` and `change` events.

I don't understand what is the use of `this` object that the callback receives.  it appears to be the jquery-ui slider object, not my Slider controller.

why should I need it, since it is also in the event.target field?

how do I access the Slider object from its method?

should I read the documentation?  (links **into** the docs appreciated!)

please bear with me and accept some coffee- instead of javascript.

```
class Slider
  constructor: (itemId, @managed=[]) ->
    $('#' + itemId).slider
      value: 0
      orientation: "horizontal"
      min: 0
      max: 255
      length: 255
      animate: true
      slide: @onChange
      change: @onChange

  onChange: (event, ui) ->
    console.log this # the jquery-ui slider
    ...
```

is there any "best" or at least common/working practice?

Comment: @mblase75, looooooool, excellent comparison.

Comment: I don't know CoffeeScript and so I don't have an opinion about whether it's good or bad.  But I do know Ikea, and you can bet I'm going to keep that analogy on file for future use!

Comment: `Slider.prototype.onChange`.  This looks kinda fishy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a shorthand for binding:

Change

```
onChange: (event, ui) ->
```

to

```
onChange: (event, ui) =>
```

and see what happens ([relevant doc section](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#classes)).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, not just jQuery or jQuery UI, `this` almost always refers to the object that is calling the method. For example:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(){
    //inside here, 'this' refers to the .myDiv HTML element object because that's what's calling this anonymous callback function.
});
```

I said "almost" always above because there are ways that you can force `this` to refer to something else, but I'm guessing that's not what is happening in your case.

If you post some code, I could be more specific about what `this` refers to in your particular case.

Comment: the trick is in facts behind "there are ways (to) force `this` to refer to something else (than the object that is calling the (function)".  I intentionally replace "method" with "function", since it is sort of confusing, inside of a method, to see `this` to be something that is unrelated to the class.  coffeescript cleans up things nicely with that `=>` operator.  in javascript one must work around the language design...

Answer (score 0):

The `this` value in JavaScript will change based on the way in which the function is invoked.  The caller can make `this` be virtually anything they'd like.  Typically in frameworks like jQuery the `this` value for an event handler is the DOM element on which the event occurred.

In this scenario though it's unclear what `this` will be because we only see the handler not the invocation.

```
Slider.prototype.onChange = function (event, ui) { 
  ...
}
```

In order to explain what `this` is we'd need to see the usage of `onChange`.  For example

```
var slider = new Slider();
slider.onChange();  // this === slider in onChange

var obj = {};
slider.onChange.apply(obj); // this === obj
```

Comment: the callbacks are invoked by the framework, so in this scenario it is the slider widget.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the event handler refers to the slider.

```
$("#slider").slider({
    change: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

When you move this slider, it will print the element with `id=slider` to the console.  There is no `Slider` object created, jQueryUI simply attaches a bunch of styles and behaviors to the selected elements to provide a slider functionality.

> should I read the documentation?

Always.

Comment: a slider widget is created in the constructor of my `Slider` class. I register the onChange method of `Slider` as callbacks for the some events of the slider widget.  but I need to access data in the `Slider` object and all I can think of is by means of global variables, which I consider bad practice.

Comment: you could chain a `.data("Slider", this)` after the initialization so you can associate a Slider object with a DOM element.  In the callback, you can retrieve it with `$(this).data("Slider")`

Comment: sounds good enough, will try it tomorrow.  the `_.bind` trick makes things neater I think, but this would avoid the extra dependency.

Comment: You can also avoid the extra dependency with [jQuery's proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

summarizing some of the answers and comments, here and elsewhere.

---

### underscore

a colleague pointed me at [underscore](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore), the part where I am associating the method to the event has become this:

```
    slide: _.bind(this.onChange, this),
    change: _.bind(this.onChange, this)
```

which looks good enough and works as expected.

but adds a dependency... :(

---

### jQuery

as @Dennis pointed out, one can do the same, staying in jQuery.

```
    slide: $.proxy(this.onChange, this),
    change: $.proxy(this.onChange, this)
```

which is possibly what I would use if I was not in coffeescript.  I'm using jQuery anyway!  but I don't really get the reason behind the name of the function.  `_.bind` makes more sense to me.

---

### coffeescript

in coffeescript one uses the **=>** operator, a practical shorthand for what I was looking for: it's just ONE character difference from my initial guess.  its javascript equivalent may interest the ones not interested in coffeescript.

**coffeescript**

```
class Slider
  constructor: (@itemId) ->
    @slider = $('#' + @itemId).slider
      value: 0
      orientation: "horizontal"
      change: @onChange

  onChange: (event, ui) =>
    ###
    ...
    ###
```

**javascript**

```
var Slider;
var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
Slider = (function() {
  function Slider(itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.onChange = __bind(this.onChange, this);
    this.slider = $('#' + this.itemId).slider({
      value: 0,
      orientation: "horizontal",
      change: this.onChange
    });
  }
  Slider.prototype.onChange = function(event, ui) {
    /*
        ...
        */
  };
  return Slider;
})();
```